# How Clear the Navigation History of Webview in Windows Store App

Tags: windows-store-apps

How Clear the Navigation History of Webview in Windows Store App (Windows 8.1)

//My WebView name is MyWebView

MyWebView.Source= null; //Gives Exception

Is there any other way to clear Webview Navigation History

Answer (score 0):

//My WebView name is MyWebView

//To Clear DataContext

MyWebView.ClearValue(WebView.DataContextProperty);

//To Clear Width

MyWebView.ClearValue(WebView.WidthProperty);

//To Clear Height

MyWebView.ClearValue(WebView.HeightProperty);

Comment: Although what you mention is a good way to clear properties, it doesn't clear the navigation history of the web view, it just removes the source url

Comment: yes, it is like creating a new instance for a property of an object. Thank's very much for your reply F.D.F Dev